# FIND all tables I need to join to get relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I want to join two tables without columns that I can join them, how can I find all the tables to reach to this two tables?

For example: I need to join the `Table A` to `table D` and to do that I need to connect  `A` to `B` and then to `C` and at the end to `D`.

My question is: can I find the tables `B` and `C`  among thousands of tables in the database without searching table by table?

Thanks a lot,
Ohad

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (For all 1000's of tables... Probably a design issue!)

Comment: It's perfectly possible (in general) for there to be multiple foreign keys and paths between two arbitrary tables. So there isn't a way to find "the" path between tables.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101444/finding-all-joins-required-to-programmatically-join-a-table

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that:

1. You want to automate this process
2. You have FOREIGN KEY constraints that you can rely on

You should proceed as follows:

1. Query sys.foreign_keys and create a directed graph structure that will contain the links between tables.
2. Then implement a graph search algorithm that will start from table A and try to find a path to table D and from D to A.
3. Once you have found the path, it will be easy to construct dynamic SQL containing the join of all tables on the path. You will need to query sys.foreign_key_columns as well to be able to construct the ON clauses of the JOIN's.

Let me know if you need help with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do to help your cause, but for the most part, there's no direct way and you would need to know how your database is structured and the purposes of the tables. Furthermore, based on the database's design, it might be very difficult for you to intuitively find your answer and you might need just need to get guidance from someone who is knowledgeable with the database design. Regardless:

**Fields in your tables A & D:**
you can look at primary fields or unique fields in the tables to determine what other tables may link to those table. Usually they are named in a way that match those other tables and you can tell what table they're coming from.

**Information_Schema Views**
You can use information_schema.tables and information_schema.column views to easily search for names of tables and columns across the entire database and narrow your search to less tables.

Comment: "I don't know a way to do this" is a much safer expression than "there's no way to do this"....because very often there is a way, you just don't happen to know of it! :)